# Rank function inconsistency with the expected output in R

Tags: r

As I read about rank function, it has Ties.method to specify what happens when ties occur.

In this vector: c(2,3,4,4,5,6), As [Matt Krause](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34008/how-does-ties-method-argument-of-rs-rank-function-work) suggested:

**average** assigns each tied element the "average" rank. The ranks would therefore be 1, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 5, 6

**first** lets the "earlier" entry "win", so the ranks are in numerical order (1,2,3,4,5,6)

**min** assigns every tied element to the lowest rank, so you get 1,2,3,3,5,6

**max** does the opposite: tied elements get the highest rank (1,2,4,4,5,6)

**random** breaks ties randomly, so you'd get either (1,2,3,4,5,6) or (1,2,4,3,5,6).

**BUT**, I need this output: (1,2,3,3,**4**,**5**). What can I do for that?

I want to use the output to fill in another matrix (X) which has 5 columns. The final output for this instance should be : (1,1,2,1,1), which means that we have 2 of the third-ranked item and one of the rest.

Now, if we have (2,3,4,4,5,6) as instance 1 and (2,3,3,3,4,2) as instance 2, in matrix (X), they will be converted to:

(1,1,2,1,1)

(2,3,1,0,0)

(the number of the columns of matrix (X) equals to the number of unique values in all instances; considering that all numbers are between 2 to 6 which means we have 5 different values in total) ...

I think rank does not work in this situation correctly.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the general relationship between the initial vector $(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5)$ and your target vector $(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5)$? They look awfully similar to one another~

Comment: Since  (2,3,3,3,4,2)  has 2 2's,   why isn't the result (2,3,1,0,0) ?

Comment: It sounds like you are merely tabulating the sorted values of the data.  Whatever you might be doing, your question seems to have nothing to do with the title, which asks how `rank` works in `R`.  Except for the extra zeros at the end of your output, the solution in base `R` is to apply the `table` function.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I change the number to make it more clear. Imagine numbers are from 2 to 6. (2,3,4,4,5,6) should become (1,2,3,3,4,5). and (2,3,3,3,4,2) should become (2,3,1,0,0). I changed also the title. @G5W I revised it.

Comment: Let me repeat: you are *tabulating*, not ranking, and the proper `R` solution is the `table` function.

Comment: It is not tabulating @whuber. Imagine the problem when I have 5 numbers. 2, 18, 19, 29, 100. If I was given c(2,2,18,100,18) I expect (1,1,2,4,2) is expected as ranking output. For the last part, I have some restrictions which I can not use a table since rows are autocorrelated. I will try to add simplified code to my question.

Comment: I can see you aren't even attempting to run `table`--you're merely speculating.  Try it and see what happens.  The restrictions about "autocorrelated rows" are mysterious, given that nothing you have described so far is related to or affected by any autocorrelation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient/shorter way to compute the unique values of the union of all instances, but otherwise this is pretty much as @whuber suggested in the comments:

Test case:

```
instances <- list(c(2,3,4,4,5,6),c(2,3,3,3,4,2))
```

The only tricky part is making sure we have the full range of levels so that zeros get counted properly:

```
ulevs <- sort(unique(Reduce(union,instances)))
f <- function(x) {
   table(factor(x,levels=ulevs))
}
```

Apply and convert to a matrix:

```
t(sapply(instances,f))
##      2 3 4 5 6
## [1,] 1 1 2 1 1
## [2,] 2 3 1 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code was nice for the second part but do you have a suggestion for ranking? My matrix actually is segmented matrix out of sequences with different length. Your code after 10 minutes still working and not finished. I have only 12000 instances (sequences) with 420 unique value.

Comment: I (along with the commenters) don't understand what you mean by ranking. My code solves the example problem you gave. If you need something else, you need to try to construct a reproducible example that's closer to what you need. (If you know the unique values already you can put them directly into the `levels` argument)